# EF5 Migration error

Tags: migration, entity-framework-5

I'm getting this error (**with AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;**) when I try to

```
Update-Database
```

**Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.**

In the __MigrationHistory table I see just one migration, that was successfully made yesterday.

What does it means with "write the pending model changes to a code-based migration" and how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that you have made some changes to your model, i.e. your .NET classes, that are not yet reflected in code based migration classes.

Executing "Add-Migration" will achieve the request to "write the pending model changes to a code-based migration".

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, certain changes like column renames require code migrations. If this is the case, you may need to add-migration first in order to stub out those changes.

I am not sure if that will disable automatic migrations or not but it's worth a try. Trial and error are my best tools for understanding stuff.  :)